# Disable Hourly Price in WooCommerce with Booking and rental system plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have a rental website using WooCommerce and [Booking and rental system](https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking-and-rental-system-woocommerce/) plugins.

I would like to Not include hourly prices in this website. So I tried to google and checked there are no option to disable the hourly prices for rental products.

I've checked the plugin code if anything I can do and seen this:

```
if(isset($rental_data['rental_days_and_costs'])){
    if($rental_data['rental_days_and_costs']['days'] > 0){
      $custom_data[] = array(
            'name'    => 'Total Days',
            'value'   => $rental_data['rental_days_and_costs']['days'],
                        'display' => ''
                    );
    } else {
      $custom_data[] = array(
            'name'    => 'Total Hours',
            'value'   => $rental_data['rental_days_and_costs']['hours'],
                        'display' => ''
        ;
    }
}
```

in the Booking and rental system plugin source code at **`includes\class-redq-product-cart.php`**.

I would like to know if anyone has dealt this before or any customization is possible. I tried but nothing seems to be working I mean it doesn't disable the feature.

**My Scenario**:

In the website, when a customer selects the date, like from 20/11/2017 and to 20/11/2017, then it counts hourly price as in the plugin given (In the dashboard precisely) **Hourly price will be applicable if booking or rental days min 1day**. But works fine for the general price when the date range is like this from 20/11/2017 and to 22/11/2017. So I just want to enable the date-wise rental price.

Comment: `My client asked for not to include hourly prices in the website` `So I just want to enable the date-wise rental price.` It looks likes you asking two different questions

Comment: Actually not @Masivuye Cokile. Sorry for any kind of misunderstanding. I just want to enable the date-wise rental. If the dates are between 20/11/2017 to 20/11/2017, then it should include one day rent, not hourly.

Comment: I've made it work @LoicTheAztec. It took a while and gone through a no. of `PHP` files. Thanks.

Comment: @AT-2017 You should add an edit at the end of your question, telling people how you solve it… thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it and it took a while as I was used to work with 'PHP' earlier. So here are the steps that I used to disable the hourly price feature:

Firstly let me write it is almost impossible for me to disable the feature from the `WordPress` dashboard. If anyone can, let me know. So what I did, I started to customize the plugin code and here is the link of the plugin - [WooCommerce Rental and Booking Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking-and-rental-system-woocommerce/)

First open the **class-redq-product-cart.php** file that's inside the **wp-content** folder and here is the file path - **wp-content\plugins\booking-and-rental-system-woocommerce\includes**. I changed a bit of code in the function **redq_rental_get_item_data()** at line no. 98 (I use Dev PHP) as the following:

```
if(isset($rental_data['rental_days_and_costs'])){
   if($rental_data['rental_days_and_costs']['days'] > 0) {
        $custom_data[] = array(
          'name'    => 'Total Days',
          'value'   => $rental_data['rental_days_and_costs']['days'],
          'display' => ''
        );
    } else {
        $custom_data[] = array( //Initially you'll have hourly rent details here - Just replace with this for per day rental
           'name'    => 'Total Days',
           'value'   => 1,
          'display' => ''
        );
    }
```

In the same file, there is another method named **redq_rental_order_item_meta()** at line no. 175 and be careful, in this section days and hours are calculated. To force not to count the hourly price, I replace the earlier code with the following:

```
if($hours < 24) {
    $days = 1; //Initially this would be $days = 0 and replace it
    $total_hours = ceil($days);
}
```

The above is done for the back-end part using `PHP` and now come for the front-end with `jQuery`. In the front-end, you have to reflect the pricing instantly for the per day rental as an example something like this:

[image: Sample Front-End Image]

For this, you have to open a file called **cost-handle.js** and the file path is **wp-content\plugins\booking-and-rental-system-woocommerce\assets\js**. Just replace the code with the following at line no 55 and remember this is a `JavaScript` file (If you wish to see the defined file name in the `PHP` file, see this at line no. 234 - **wp-content\plugins\booking-and-rental-system-woocommerce\redq-rental-and-bookings.php**):

```
if(hours < 24) {
    days = 1; //make the day 1 and initailly it's defined 0
    total_hours = Math.ceil(hours);

    $('.additional_person_info').trigger("chosen:updated");

    $('.show_person_cost_if_day').hide();
    $('.show_person_cost_if_time').show();

    //$('.show_if_day').children('.amount').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
    $('.show_if_day').children('span').hide();
    $('.show_if_time').show();

    $('.rnb_single_add_to_cart_button').removeAttr('disabled','disabled');                             
}
```

I hope, this will help others to solve the issue and tried my best to solve and make understand.

**The scenario that it worked** - I am writing again, this works when you have anything for rental within the same date range. Suppose, from 22/11/2017 and to 22/11/2017. This is fine if it's for hourly price and for the same date written. By default, in the dashboard, for this date range, `WooCommerce` counts for hourly price and to forcefully disable this, you have to go through code-behind.

Comment: This is very helpful in a certain way… but overriding plugin core files is not a good track. Anyway congats!

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec for the suggestion and yes, even I was really scared if I missed any of the lines. Definitely not recommended.